# How to invoke Hyper-V Enhanced Session screen resolution prompt?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, windows-10-v1607

When using client Hyper-V in Windows 10, the first time you switch on Enhanced Session for VM it prompts you to select resolution, then remembers your selection and never prompts again it seems. Where does resolution setting get stored, or how can I force this screen resolution prompt again to change the selected resolution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use cmd.exe and type:

`VMConnect.exe <ServerName> <VMName> /edit`

P.S.: You can also share local hard drive (Show Options ->tab Local Resources->Local devices and resources->More) as on normal windows remote desktop session :-)

You may need to have the VM started for this to work.
You may need to run this from an admin prompt if on localhost.

Comment: Not sure why it has been downvoted, but I just tested and "VMConnect.exe <ServerName> <VMName> /edit" indeed does the trick - I have my screen resolution prompt :) Thanks for your response.

Comment: I think this required 2012 or later? Doesn't seem to work on 2008R2.

Comment: Unfortunately, [my proposed edit to the above](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/777136) was rejected by the community. However, this answer is incomplete and not useful without the additional information that using the /edit often will not work until the VM is already running. So, if you can't get the above to work, start the VM first in the Hyper-V Manager without connecting to it, then run the VMConnect.exe command line with the /edit option.

Comment: It didn't work when I try to connect to Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: If you are on Powershell and want to copy and paste the name of your vm you can use this command "Get-VM". This will print out every VM you have on your local machine.

Comment: `Windows 10 pro 21H1`, Works by just running `VMConnect.exe` and it will give you a nice GUI to choose the server/guest

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me. Save yourself the headache: load CMD as admin and use this one-line solution. Next time you enter an enhanced session it will return (and UNCHECK the collapsed "save for future sessions" if you aren't ready to make these semi-permanent!).

Comment: @Abdelouahab I needed to run as admin to get that to work. And it just shows the std connection window which does not let you change the saved remote display settings. Server name can be "localhost".

Comment: This works like a charm with Window 10 Pro and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Thanks you very much :-)

Comment: Not working in Windows 11 Pro. :( Neither does the "disable/enable enhanced session" work-around.

Comment: Does not work on Windows 11 for some reason.

Answer (score 40):

There's a much easier way - after lots of research!

- Close the VM client down
- Change the Hyper-V Manager settings (right-hand window of the Hyper-V console)
  [image: Hyper-V Manager Setting]
- Under Server -> Enhanced Session Mode Policy, simply:

  - Uncheck Allow Enhanced Session mode
  - Apply
  - Re-check Allow Enhanced Session Mode (this will reset).
  - Apply again

[image: Enhance Session Mode]

- Now Start the VM in question but don't connect yet.

[image: Start the VM]

- Wait for the VM to start then right-click the VM in the console
- You should see "Edit Session Settings" option
- Click this and the original dialogue will appear again.

Done.

Comment: This method also didn't show "Edit Session Settings"  when connecting to Windows 7 Enterprise. But it worked for Windows 10

Comment: "Edit session settings" option doesn't appear for me because vmconnect does not list the virtual machine(s). This is due to user permissions for localhost. I'm on a domain controlled PC.

Comment: Good job finding a deeply buried configuration for an otherwise simple setting.

Comment: It didn't work for me, an even better solution is to change resolution settings in guest OS, ie. right click desktop and display settings. and window will auto resize!

Comment: You omitted a crucial step: under the server name, you must click on **Hyper-V Settings...**. Only then do you see **Enhanced Session Mode** on the left, and clicking that shows the option you referred to.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Followed instructions up until the 'You should see "Edit Session Settings" option' step, at which point I did not see that option.

Comment: Excellent work, this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

#### Enhanced Session configuration/settings files:

- The configuration files for each VM's enhanced session settings can be found in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Client\1.0`
- The file naming scheme is `vmconnect.rdp.<VMGUID>.config`
- Each .config file contains 15 or 16 settings (15 for ver 8.0 and lower VMs, 16 for ver 8.1 VMs and higher).  Two settings relating to the question are:

  - `"SaveButtonChecked"` which, if changed to `False`, will force the connection settings dialog to open the next time a connection is made to that VM
  - `"DesktopSize"` which stores the resolution
- Deleting a VM's .config file in this directory will also force the connection settings dialog to open

---

### Open the connection settings dialog using Hyper-V Manager:

- When a VM is running and Enhanced RDP Sessions can be established, `Edit Session Settings...` will appear in the Action Pane (right-hand side)

  [image: Edit Session Settings...]

### Open the connection settings dialog using vmconnect.exe

- `vmconnect.exe "VMServerName" "VMName" -G "VMGUID" -C 0 /edit`
- If there are multiple VMs that use the same VMName (e.g. 2x VMs named `"Server1"`):

  - `vmconnect.exe "VMServerName" "Server1" /edit` will always open the first instance of `Server1` (and will never open the second instance) -- which is why using the the `-G "VMGUID"` argument (either by itself or together with `"VMName"`) is beneficial.
  - If opening multiple vmconnect.exe instances, incrementing the `-C` argument by 1 each time it is run will stagger the window positions, making each `vmconnect.exe` window easier to see.

### To Find out if a VM can establish an enhanced RDP session:

- `(Get-VMHost).EnableEnhancedSessionMode` will tell you if Enhanced Session Mode is enabled on the VM server
- On a VM Server, you can query the WMI namespace `ROOT/virtualization/v2` and the `Msvm_ComputerSystem` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/msvm-computersystem) for a given VM

  - The `EnhancedSessionModeState` property returns a `uint16` value:

    | Value | Description | Meaning |
    | --- | --- | --- |
    | 2 | Allowed and avaliable | Enhanced mode is allowed and available on the virtual machine |
    | 3 | Not allowed | Enhanced mode is not allowed on the virtual machine |
    | 6 | Allowed but not available | Enhanced mode is allowed and but not currently available on the virtual machine |

    ```
    $VMId = 'fde3a5fa-2fbf-4010-8ea0-5d8fdd2c50ad'
    $CimParams = @{
        Namespace   = 'ROOT/virtualization/v2'
        ClassName   = 'Msvm_ComputerSystem'
        Filter      = "Name = '$VMId'"
        Property    = 'EnhancedSessionModeState'
    }
    (Get-CimInstance @CimParams).EnhancedSessionModeState
    ```

Answer (score 1):

All I do is close the window and reconnect, and it prompts me for the Display configuration settings again (Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager)

Comment: The problem is if "save for future sessions" is checked it's impossible to get these options back via the GUI